# getting jQuery Ajax return data in Asp.Net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, jquery

I'm a newbie in jQuery and don't understand how in jQuery Ajax returns data. I have some simple function to get some data like below

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = false)]
protected int SignIn()
{
    return 0;
}
```

and in my .aspx page I have this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#si").click(function 
            () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "SignIn.aspx/SignIn",
                contentType: "application/json",
                success: function (txt) {
                    alert(txt);
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

but in alert I get the whole SignIn.aspx (all html tags and so on). how to alert the 0 which the SignIn() returns?thanks

Comment: the function SignIn is in .asmx webservice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are asking an ASPX file for data and I think that should be an ASMX.

Check out Dave Ward's post where I leaned about all this: http://encosia.com/asp-net-web-services-mistake-manual-json-serialization/

The simplest example I could make looks like this:

Add a Web Service (ASMX) containing

```
using System.Web.Services;

[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class WebService : System.Web.Services.WebService {
   [WebMethod]
   public int Status(int input) {
      return input + 1;
   }
}
```

Then in your HTML do

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="jquery-1.6.2.min.js" ></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
  $(function () {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'WebService.asmx/Status',
      data: '{ input: 0 }',
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      contentType: 'application/json',
      success: function (data, status) {
        alert(data);
        alert(typeof data);
      }
    });
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

In the ajax call the string defined in data is the input to the web method. Names must match. In the success callback, the first alert shows the value returned (input plus one) and the second alert shows that it is a number, not a string. Because the datatype is set to JSON, the web method returns JSON allowing the data to be typed correctly.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

Make the `SignIn` method static and public and show alert with following code: `alert(txt.d);`

Comment: try to use `alert(txt);` Explanation of d property here: http://encosia.com/never-worry-about-asp-net-ajaxs-d-again/

Answer (score 3):

Try this sample. I have passed the id from aspx to handler and just returned from there to show the server side data to aspx again

this is sample  example .....

Handler code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace TestProject
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for TestHandler1
    /// </summary>
    public class TestHandler1 : IHttpHandler
    {

        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            string id = context.Request["id"];
            context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
            context.Response.Write(id);
        }

        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and in aspx

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'TestHandler.ashx?id='+ 1,
                data: 'id=' + 1,
                success: function (msg) {
                    alert(msg);
                }
            });

        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That will give back the number passed in as a string, but I suspect the OP would like JSON data returned, so the int is an int.

Comment: @nickd the op said "jQuery and don't understand how in jQuery Ajax returns data"  .. I am explaining this as sample to that comment..

Comment: thanks, but I don't get it exactly, you used POST in ajax but used the url to send data? is the url only for detecting the method?

Comment: The response write is what will be returned... you could build the json and write it. if the json is valid, it can be used the same way...