# How to call c# method with no parameters and access returned data?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

So I have seen many examples such as these : 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8094230/2525507

```
public class WebService : System.Web.Services.WebService {
   [WebMethod]
   public List<string> getList() {
      return new List<string> {"I", "Like", "Stack", "Overflow"};
   }
}
```

Where you just it seems that through the success function you can view the returned data from the c# method in the form of an alert. But what if I want to access this "input+1" data outside of the function call, how would I proceed to do that? Also I am not sure how to call a method that has no parameters?

```
<body>

<select id="wordSelect">
// Drop Down Menu to be populated 
</select>

<script>
  $(function () {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'WebService.asmx/getList',
      data: '{**NO PARAMETERS?!**}', // should I also call JSON.stringify?
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      contentType: 'application/json',
      success: function (data, status) {
        alert(data);
        alert(typeof data);
      }
    });
  });

 $.each(data.i, function(index, item) { // will this access "I", "Like", ... etc?
     $(#wordSelect).append(
         $("<option></option>")
             .text(item)
     );
 };
</script>

</body>
```

In the end, I would like to populate a dropdown list using returned JSON data from a c# method that has been called through ajax, but I'm not sure how I can play with that retrieved JSON data that seems to be stuck in the function call?

Sorry, I am new to Jquery/AJAX/etc... But Thank you so much!

Comment: ajax call is asynchronous, so you have to process everything in the `success` callback. If you want to do something outside, you have to prepare some callback, add code there and call that callback inside the `success` callback.

Comment: can you show the json response of webservice from console

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your method takes no arguments, just don't specify the data property on the ajax call

```
<script>
  $(function () {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'WebService.asmx/getList',
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json', //make sure your service is actually returning json here
      contentType: 'application/json',
      success: function (data, status) {
        //here data is whatever your WebService.asmx/getList returned
        //populate your dropdown here with your $.each w/e
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Also I could be wrong, but the WebService method you showed, doesn't look like it will return json.  I think you will have to serialize, or set the content type or something similar.  (Been along time since I've used the asmx type services)

Comment: Thank you guys! Sorry this was such a trivial question, but I really couldn't Google with the correct terminology or find apt examples. Thank you thank you thank you!

Comment: So I have tried to just access data in my success call, but I keep getting an error saying "data" is undefined? Any ideas?

Comment: is data the first parameter of your success callback?

Comment: It's all good turns out my my webservice was nested and I messed up the url.

Answer (score 0):

See my answer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/777523/asp-net-ajax-vs-jquery-in-asp-net-mvc/778853#778853).  I reference a web site called Encosia, written by Dave Ward.  He has an excellent series on using Ajax with ASP.net / MVC.  That is a great place to start, with numerous examples.