# Why I can't send parameter to action method with ajax?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

This code works without sending parameter:

```
$(function () {
        $('#Fee').on('focus', function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("GetFee")', 
                dataType: "json", 
                type: "POST",
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 
                cache: false, 
                data: { }, 
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.success) {
                        $('#Fee').val(data.message);
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

However if I want to send a parameter to the `GetFee` action method it doesn't work anymore:

```
data: { bookname : 'book1' }
```

And I changed my action method to accept parameter:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetFee(string bookname)
```

Comment: Remove the `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',` option (your not stringifying the data)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Can you please explain more?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call c# method with no parameters and access returned data?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24500744/how-to-call-c-sharp-method-with-no-parameters-and-access-returned-data)

Comment: @un-lucky how is it a duplicate? Have you even read the title? The question is clearly about *passing parameters* to an action method.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You indicated:

```
contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
```

so make sure that you respect what you claimed to be sending to the server:

```
data: JSON.stringify({ bookname : 'book1' })
```

On the other hand, if you get rid of this `application/json` content type in your request, jQuery will use `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` by default and then you can simply use this:

```
data: { bookname : 'book1' }
```

Comment: Thanks. But what's the stringify means?

Comment: It serializes the javascript object that you have (`{ bookname : 'book1' }`) to a JSON string: `"{ \"bookname\": \"book1\" }"` and it sends this JSON string over the wire. When you write `data: { bookname : 'book1' }` here's what gets sent over the wire: `bookname=book1` which as you can see is not a valid JSON string. Please use the built-in developer toolbar of your browser to inspect the differences between those approaches in the payloads being sent to the server. Also checkout: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Answer (score 1):

Since you are specifying the datatype 'json'. So you can send only json object in request. So you need to convert data in json format.

You can do by using the **JSON.stringify()** method. The [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) method converts a JavaScript value to a JSON string.

```
JSON.stringify(value[, replacer[, space]])
```

If you don't want to use JSON datatype, you don't need to convert it.
**Simply use:**

```
$(function () {
    $('#Fee').on('focus', function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("GetFee")', 
            type: "POST",
            cache: false, 
            data: { 
               'bookname' : 'book1'
            }, 
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.success) {
                    $('#Fee').val(data.message);
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As Darin Dimitrov had previously replied, you don't send your  data in the format where you declare in the contentType.
In my opinion you can choose these two ways:

1.Send your parameter like a JSON string (look at Darin Dimitrov's answer) and add a [FromBody] before the input parameter, to clarify where you want to read this value.

```
[HttpPost]
 public ActionResult GetFee([FromBody] string bookname)
```

2.Avoid specifying the contentType, and dataType in your ajax call, like this

```
$(function () {
    $('#Fee').on('focus', function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("GetFee")',                 
            type: "POST",                
            cache: false, 
            data: { bookname : 'book1' },
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.success) {
                    $('#Fee').val(data.message);
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```